# Java: Exception Help Char and Int

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throws

Ok all, I'm stuck again with this code.

I need to put in an Exception that won't allow the user to input 0 (because you can't divide later by 0) and the user cannot enter alpha characters. I am trying to display the message, disregard the wrong input, and loop to allow the user to try again until they put in the acceptable number.

Here is what I have:

```
package exceptionhandler;

/**
 *
 * @author Sarah
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments10 10
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Please enter ten values:");
        System.out.println();
    // Input the data into array from the user.
        double[ ] digit = new double[11];
        int sum = 0;
        //Declare an array
        try
        {
        for (int i = 1; i < digit.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Value " + i + ": ");
            digit[i] = (double)in.nextInt();
            sum += (int)digit[i];
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("You Can Only Enter Numbers!");
         }
        }

        System.out.println("Total Values in Array:"+ sum);
         // Calculate the sum and print the total


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would you like to divide the values?");
        System.out.println("Yes or No to Exit the Program");
        String a = input.next();


         if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){   
                double [] divisionResult = new double[digit.length / 2];
    //Division array declared
                for (int i = 1; i < digit.length; i += 2)
                {
                double result = digit[i];
                if (result > digit[i + 1]) 
                result = result / digit[i + 1]; 
        else {
                result = digit[i + 1] / result;
            }
                divisionResult [i / 2] = result;
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
            }
        else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
           System.exit(0);
        }
        }
}
```

I have tried declaring the throw exception and then tried a try..catch. But it is not recognizing catch and try talking to one another... so I know I am doing something wrong, but I can't see where it should go.

Is the Exception in the right place? Should I have done something else? Is my exception written wrong? How can I then move on to prevent the input of zero as well- rethrow?

Help?

Comment: The try statement doesn't make sense here, you want another "}" before catch, and you don't need the other "}" after the catch block. As it stands, you're trying to catch something without finishing the try block.

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to be `InputMismatchException` not `NumberFormatException` to catch an exception upon entering characters and you need to check for **0** if the user input 0 and `deduct 1` the current index of the for-loop to let the user try again.

**sample:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < digit.length; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Value " + i + ": ");
            digit[i] = (double) in.nextInt();
            sum += (int) digit[i];
            if(digit[i] == 0.0)
            {
                System.out.println("You cant enter 0: try again");
                --i;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("You Can Only Enter Numbers!");
            --i;
            in.nextLine(); //to consume the character
        }
    }
```

**result:**

```
Please enter ten values:
Value 1: 0
You cant enter 0: try again
Value 1: asd
You Can Only Enter Numbers!
Value 1:
```